# How to change JProfiler font size

Tags: jprofiler

Environment: JProfiler 8.1.2 under Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, x86_64, Unity desktop.

How can the font(s) be changed?  Particularly the size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fonts have the standard font sizes from the look and feel. The font sizes cannot be changed in JProfiler.